# How to mock functions in Python in order to change default keyword arguments

Tags: python, mocking, keyword-argument

I'm using the mock library and unittest2 in order to test different aspects of my software project.

At the moment I have the following question: is it possible to mock a function so that the default keyword argument is different, but the functionality remains?

Say I have the following code

```
class C():
  def fun(self, bool_arg = True):
    if bool_arg:
      return True
    else
      return False
```

What if I want to mock C.fun:

```
C.fun = mock.Mock(???)
```

so that every instance of C will replace keyword 'bool_arg' with False, instead of True and the result of:

```
c = C()
c.fun()
```

returns:

> False

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also try to wrap your function. Something on the line of

```
def wrapper(func, bool_arg):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['bool_arg']=bool_arg
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

and

```
class C():
    def fun(...):
        ...

c = C()
c.fun = wrapper(fun, False)
```

should work

**Edit**

If you want to change the default for the class and not for a particular instance you can create a derived class and redefine `fun` wrapping the method of `C`. Something on the line (I don't have now the time to test it):

```
class D(C):
    def fun(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = wrapper(C.f, False)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then about the suggestion of @Ber, you can define `def wrapper(func, **wrapkwargs)` and then instead of `kwargs['bool_arg']=bool_arg` do

```
for i in wrapkwargs.iteritems():  #wrapkwargs is a dictionary
    kwargs[i[0]] = i[1]
```

Comment: Nice. Thid could be extended to wrap any function, supplying any list of keyword args.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was actually looking for replacing the Class default keyword argument to be replaced for every instance of it. But I adapted your solution a little so that instead of:    c.fun = wrapper(...) I did:    class C.fun = wrapper(...). And it worked for all instances!

Comment: Ber, how would you generalize the above to accept any keyword argument that one wants to wrap ?

Comment: @mpaf you mean that you have changed the implementation of class C substituting self.fun with a wrapped version?

Comment: @mpaf: if you want to get a better understanding of wrapper (and consequently decorators) I suggest you to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/1860757 and http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/

Comment: yes that's what I meant. But actually I now fail to get it working on my actual (more complex) class which has more keyword and non-keyword arguments. I get "TypeError: got multiple values for keyword argument". So yes I probably don't understand wrappers really well. I'll check your link, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that first link, it is really good! According to that link, when you decorate a class method you should add a **self** parameter to your `def inner(self, *args,**kwargs)` so I guess that was missing from your answer? I managed to solve my problem. I was getting multiple values for keyword argument because I was invoking the function somewhere without the keyword (just following the normal function parameter order).  So it was getting passed to *args. When I then replaced the keyword in **kwargs it was actually defining a second value for the same parameter.

Comment: Now that I see, this answer does not require mock library. Wasn't mock supposed to automate or make the decoration process easier?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this code:

```
>>> import mock
>>> 
>>> class C():
...   def fun(self, bool_arg = True):
...     if bool_arg:
...       print "True"
...     else:
...       print "False"
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> funCopy = c.fun
>>> c.fun = mock.Mock(side_effect=lambda bool_arg=False: funCopy(bool_arg=bool_arg))
>>> c.fun()
False
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Did not know that you could do default variable assignment inside a `lambda`.

Comment: @jdotjdot You are right, but I think if mpaf make this question is because he can call the function changing the default variable value.

Comment: @jdotjdot in english please

Comment: @jdotjdot OK! no problem, and sorry for my english ;)

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I would have accepted it as it was the first one, but I couldn't make it work for the case that I was looking for (maybe I wasn't too explicit in my question) which was that every instance of class C gets that keyword argument replaced.